# Logging latency of a query in JPA

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, latency

I have a CRUD repository in springboot java app. I am trying to measure the latency of the query form APP perspective and log it in the logger. What is a good elegant way to achieve this please ?
I am also going to use these logs for monitoring purposes later.

Currently the way I am doing it is -

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
result = respoistoryDao.findId();
long executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis()-start;
```

How can I make this better ?

Comment: What do you want to measure? The query execution? The mapping from the query result to objects, getting a session and connection? Your question might seem simple but currently you are measuring all of what I mentioned and not just the query.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant and reusable design would be an Aspect. ([Spring AOP docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop.html))

First, create an annotation

```java
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Timed {}
```

Then create the Aspect

```java
@Slf4j
@Aspect
@Component
public class TimedAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(Timed)")
    public Object executionTimeLogger(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
        long duration = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
          
        log.info("Method: {} | Duration:  {}ms", joinPoint.getSignature(), duration);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Once you have these two pieces, just add `@Timed` to any method signature, and it will log out the duration for you.

Comment: Looks like a neat idea !
Just tried it out - for some reason it doesn`t come in the section for TimedAspect - I pushed a log in the method around which the @timed was used  - the log was emitted from inside, but debugger did`nt reach inside the TimedAspect.